# C# website get new form action site?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, post

I'd like to make an application that AUTOMATICALLY gets a list of books from a site "http://www.sbn.it/opacsbn/opac/iccu/free.jsp". The problem is this: after you write the keyword of the book the html page moves you to another page, using the "action" attribute of the html form. How can I automatically give a name to the textbox of the page, submit the "Cerca" button and get the code of the new page (the one where the results are listed)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're asking how to make HTTP requests and receive their responses in code.  Something like the `System.Net.WebClient` class would allow this.  Naturally, if the target site has an API, you'll want to integrate with that.  But if you're going to be scraping information from their page manually then you'll need to reverse-engineer the HTTP requests made from your browser and mimic those requests in code.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I really don't know where to start from. Could you write some code for this?

Comment: You have entirely misunderstood what Stack Overflow does.  Start with some tutorials on C#.  Search for things like "C# webclient example", and check the MSDN documentation page for that class.  Make *some* attempt.  We can help if you get stuck on something specific.

Comment: Ok thanks anyways. :)